# When should I use Widgets/HTML in Yii2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii2

I've been able to apply a custom Themeforest Bootstrap template in Yii2 and, being completely new to the Yii framework, am unaware of the benefits/pitfalls of using standard html-bootstrap syntax when rendering forms (search inputs, buttons, navigation) for the user.  I understand that it is discouraged to stray too far from any framework in general.  Is it worth the trouble creating widgets for each individual view or should I instead change the template very little but assign Yii functionality to bits and pieces of it?

As an example, I am using an unchanged version of a template's header/navigation with list items:

```
<li>
  <?= Html::a('Discover', ['site/discover']) ?>
</li>
<li>
  <?php if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    echo Html::a('Sign Up', ['site/signup']);
    echo "</li>";
    echo "<li>";
    echo Html::a('Login', ['site/login']);
  } else {
    echo "<form method='post'>";
    echo Html::a('Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')', ['site/logout'],[ 'data-method'=>'post']);
    echo "</form>";
  } ?>
</li>
```

This allows the bootstrap and template CSS files to remain unaffected.  But is this an acceptable way of using Yii2?  Or, should I extend each existing Bootstrap-Yii widget to get them to behave as the template's snippets already do (JS/CSS files are included anyways to even get the structure and look).  What am I losing/risking with my current approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's your choice, but It is highly recommended to use these widgets as:

- You can easily customize them
- You can benefit them to increase your development speed
- They are created to decrease development time and code size
- Using theme can increase your code readability
- They are compatible with core framework
- They satisfy security issues
- You code in PHP

For example, you can create a link like below:

```
<a href="<?= Url::toRoute('site/index'); ?>" onclick="clicked()" class="css-class">Click Here!</a>
```

But with `Html`:

```
Html::a('Click Here!', ['site/index'], ['class'=>'css-class','onclick'=>'clicked']);
```

You can find it more use while using `Widgets`:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => 2]) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Above code will generate:

```
<form id="w0" action="route" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="REdDYWZPWms2dCQlEwgQW3MKDwY5Cj89EhgtJ1UcLwwdECVQNXcIPA==">
    <div class="form-group field-name required">
        <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="Form[name]" maxlength="2">
        <div class="help-block"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is same for Yii2's bootstrap widgets. However, you can customize all of them. For example:

```
Breadcrumbs::widget([
    'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : []
]);
```

Above widget generates a breadcrumb as easy as possible. But consider an example that, you may need to make active item **Bold**. Easily:

```
Breadcrumbs::widget([
    'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
    'activeItemTemplate'=>'<li class=\"active\"><b>{link}</b></li>'
]);
```

---

To answer, when to use Widgets? I suggest, forever! except when you need to do something very special which Yii widgets do not support that.

Comment: Thank you. Now I see how much easier and quicker my work can be. Great visualization of the processes that can be omitted, too!

Comment: @mijopabe You're welcome dear. Yii is really powerful. Please carefully read the documentation to benefit all of Yii's features.